# Flutter: Card widget with Dropdown

Tags: flutter, dropdown

When I click on my card widget, I want it to be dropdown according to my upcoming data. I have text and icon on my card. I added Inkwell to be clickable. but as I click, I want my coming data to be added down. Is this possible?

```
     child: Card(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {    });
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 8.0),
                                child: Icon(
                             Icons.favorite,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot.text,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

I have a list like this,

[image]

and when an item is clicked, I want related subtext as below. For example, I want 2 companies related to the country to come. Like the card open. (Sorry for the bad visuals. i did it quickly:))

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the expected result via screenshot or any design and also, what is happening with the above code? Also, why don't you use [Dropdown Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)?

Comment: I updated my question, I didn't use dropdown because I need to show my incoming data as a card separately.

Comment: Check out the answer kimSoo

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible, the whole idea is based on this theory:

> Your `country card` and it's associated `company card` should be a different `StatefulWidget`, which will be controlled by the boolean

**Please note:** I have given a very basic representation of the view, you can play with the UI and make it look like your own desired UI

This is your card view should look like:

```
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  // right now it only accepts title, but you can add more
  // arguments to be accepted by this widget
  CardWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _CardWidgetState createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  // responsible for toggle
  bool _showData = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        // list card containing country name
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() => _showData = !_showData);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, offset: Offset(0.0, 3.0))]
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // add your other icon here
                  Text(widget.title)
                ]
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        
        // this is the company card which is toggling based upon the bool
        _showData ? Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: ['Kia','Samsung'].map((e){
            // make changes in the UI here for your company card
            return Card(child: Text(e));
          }).toList()
        ) : SizedBox() // else blank
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Here how I am calling the `CardWidget` in the main UI

```dart
       // this is dummy data, you can play with the data and the UI
       Column(
          children: ['Korea', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA', 'India'].map((country){
              // returning the CardWidget passing only title
              return CardWidget(title: country);
          }).toList()
        )
```

**Result**

[image: Result GIF]